# Does the smallest DFA equivalent to this NFA requires at least $O(2^n)$ state?

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

The wikipedia page [*Powerset construction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) says that the DFA equivalent to this $(n + 1)$-state NFA (with $n=4$ here) "requires $2^n$ states, one for each $n$-character suffix of the input".

[image: The smallest DFA for this (n+1)-states NFA according to Wikipedia.]

I understand that the author wants to say that the smallest DFA equivalent to this NFA needs at least $2^n$ states.

But I can find a very much smaller DFA equivalent to this NFA just below:

[image: A same size DFA equivalent to the NFA]

Is Wikipedia wrong? Or am I? (which is much more likely)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The NFA accepts strings where the fourth letter from the end is 1. Your DFA doesn't accept 11000.

A DFA doesn't know how much input is left, so the property "the fourth character *from the end*" is difficult. You need to remember the last four characters to know whether it was a 1 or a 0 once you reach the end of the string. To do so you need a state for each possible combination of the last four characters, so 2^4 states. If you look hard at the DFA the Wikipedia gives you should be able to figure out which of the states stores which combination of characters.

Answer (score 8):

You can prove the lower bound on the number of states using Myhill-Nerode theory.

Suppose that we are given a language $L$, in this case the language over $\{0,1\}$ of words in which the $n$th last symbol is $1$. We say that two words $x,y$ (over the same alphabet) are *equivalent* if for all words $z$, $xz \in L$ iff $yz \in L$. It is easy to check that if two words $x,y$ are not equivalent, then $\delta(q_0,x) \neq \delta(q_0,y)$ for every DFA for $L$. In particular, if we can find $N$ pairwise inequivalent words, then it follows that every DFA for $L$ must contain at least $N$ states.

For our language $L$, I claim that the set of $2^n$ words of length exactly $n$ are pairwise inequivalent. Indeed, suppose that $x \neq y$ are two words of length $n$. Then $x_i \neq y_i$ for some $i$, say $x_i = 0$ and $y_i = 1$ (without loss of generality). Then $x0^{i-1} \notin L$ whereas $y0^{i-1} \in L$, since in both cases the $n$th symbol from the end is $x_i$ or $y_i$. Thus every DFA for $L$ must contain at least $2^n$ states.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Myhill-Nerode has always be unclear for me and your explanation is very easy to understand.